# Cannot perform animations of a view which is on top of a SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-camera, android-animation

[image]

Previously, I've been developed a library to facilitates the usage of Camera API: The [Camerakit](https://github.com/KazafChen/CameraKit). I'm recently developing a new project with this library and I want to perform animations on the top of camera preview(which extends SurfaceView),I found when I added such as the following code to my application, the animations of the view is not performed properly with camera preview, but performed well when without camera preview.

```
// MainActivity.class
capture.animate().yBy(2000).setDuration(10000).start();
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. By changing the preview component which is `SurfaceView` to `TextureView` solve this issue. Now I can overlay any animation on my camera preview.

I also updated my code on [Github](https://github.com/KazafChen/CameraKit).

[This commit](https://github.com/KazafChen/CameraKit/commit/3fcf76fda15c40c29cb2e0909104d57bb2a8912a) reproduces the issue. And [this one](https://github.com/KazafChen/CameraKit/commit/c012b7a4fdd9e6eeb08c4779d50c6ca635759e3e) solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem when i code android with Unity.Then I solved this problem by setting SurfaceView's level on the Z axis direction. As we all know,SurfaceView is a view which drew above the shell.Maybe you can got the SurfaceView's instance,then set it under the view.like this:`((SurfaceView)child).setZOrderOnTop(false);`
So,in fact,the animation has already run.It just be covered by SurfaceView.

Answer (score 1):

Playing around with animating camera controls over a custom camera activity and I too ran into this problem.  My camera controls would get cut off at an almost random point in their animation over the camera view.  After playing around for a few hours as well as trying out Z ordering, the thing that worked for me was adding a full size child view with a background color (transparent works fine!).  Not sure if the ordering of the view matters (I placed it right before/above the view I wanted to animate).

Answer (score 0):

if you have to use surfaceview, there is a solution, put a no-TRANSPARENT view between surfaceview and your target view.